# How safe is my code inside an ARM Cortex-M? Threat of hackers pulling it? MPU required?

Tags: arm

I have an older product that is Microchip PIC 18F based. It's being knocked off in China. The clones are a cheap copy of the hardware, but 1:1 software. It's clearly my code on these. The code is programmed at initial device assembly and never again (no updates, no bootloader, etc). So the only way this could happen is if they defeated the read protections on the PIC 18F. I don't think that's unreasonable to assume given the age and my impression of that chip that lead me to switch away from them before this came to my attention.

I've migrated all new projects to ARM (M0+, M3, M4) already for other reasons. This doesn't do anything for my old code now. I am hoping the protections are better on the ARM Cortex chips (NXP, ST, Freesale, Ti, etc). I can find very little information on how this works.

1. Is it possible to defeat the chip read protections in place on ARM? Assuming full JTAG, SerialWireDebug, whatever. Even if you decap the chip to expose the die? Even if you really knew what you were doing? How safe is it? Because... 8bit PIC is apparently extremely unsafe.
2. I had a thought that in new projects I could require connection to a our server where I would record the unique ID (96-128bit) and authorize the device from there. Clones ID's would not be recognized. This is a logistical mess because I'll have a master list from the assembler, it'll be online, the user's device code will have to be sent and authorized with a firmware download... There are a few places for spoofing and abuse. This is a hassle on many levels. Are there simpler ways of ensuring protection than this: ?

   - We record the unique id at manufacturing
   - The user locks his name/info/unique number into the part
   - The user plugs into USB
   - Our web/java software talks with module
   - We store the unique ID of the chip and their unique info
   - If the chip isn't recognized (id not in the list), stop
   - If the chip is already linked to another user's info (spoofed ID), stop
   - If it's a new or already verified module, allow the user to work with it
3. The above is under the assumption that the unique id's built into the ARM die and could never be written over. Seems likely. But every mfg seems have to a different system in place, this seems to be a peripheral feature and not part of the core (some STM chips it's 96bit, some Freescale it's 128bit). I assume this is largely what the unique ID's are for, serialization and encryption schemes.

(Note: I hate DRM. And that's not really what I'm trying to do, but this product is part of a system that could be indirectly responsible for people's lives. We cannot have cheap knockoffs from China out there for many reasons, even if the software in mine, we can't verify their cheap hardware.)

Comment: As to the MPU... I haven't looked into that a ton yet, but it seems like a configurable way to lock out regions. I'm just not sure if my unprivileged/privileged code (RTOS, threads, bootloader) is all set up for that right now. Just needs work, but maybe the MPU does more or less than what I think it does?

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually have much to do with ARM - they only design CPU cores - the flash, peripherals and other stuff built around that core (i.e. what you actually care about here) is the vendor's own doing, and can vary significantly from one to the next.

Comment: Well... I figure the JTAG/SWD, MPU, and probably unique ID are specified by ARM.

But I see your point I guess. STM32Fx is what I'm talking about in this case

Comment: On a related note, [this paper is a fun read](http://www.openpcd.org/images/HID-iCLASS-security.pdf). Skimming [a random STM32F4 TRM](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00096844.pdf) suggests that ST do have features like blowing JTAG and disabling CPU data accesses to flash, but that's not to say a sufficiently determined hacker won't still find a way if your code is valuable enough (they're still not _physically_ secure chips, after all). Given the focus, some of these aspects may be be on-topic over at [security.se] too.

Comment: The DRM piece called **secure boot** is what you want as well as *encrypted boot*.  Various Freescale product have a small tamper protected RAM cells which contain a key to decrypt code.  Attackers can fake out/snoop DRAM, on die, etc and just ripe your code from there.  You can also digitally sign code and other tools. Probably other vendors have similar offerings under NDA.  They all add headaches to product design without much benefit.  Given an ARM is a cell, someone can fake out the entire chip and read your code (knock-off cortex-m).

Comment: So nothing can be done effectively? Online authentication seems like the last best bet. In that case I suppose even a clone would fail authentication? Thanks for the comments.

Comment: If you are using a microcontroller with built in RAM and Flash such as an STM32 and do not have code in an external memory device then you can lock read access to the flash. On an STM32 this is very secure (you have to set up the lock yourself, either programatically or with the JTAG/ST-Link). You can then no longer read anything from the Flash. If you want unlock it you can, but this causes the entire flash to be erased.

Comment: @Realtime Rik Do you actually know anything about the decapping process and side channel attacks on STM32 and other similar ARM chips or are you just assuming that because those lock bits keep you out that they would keep everyone out?

Comment: Not really. I am aware of it. I think that if someone is that intent of getting at the code then there is probably not a lot you could do about it. Maybe there are processors available that provide higher security or some allow you to encrypt the flash.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following:

1. Look at ARM chips that have TrustZone and encryption. Some have per peripheral key locking.
2. If you want absolute security, then buy the arm IP and design a silicon chip with the code embedded in the hardware with no way to read/write it. Make it part of the silicon logic or an on chip ROM.